# Wildfly 9 exception "Too many open files"

Tags: wildfly

I already configure the ulimit and /proc/sys/fs/file-max as 1000000 on our server. 
  When I find "Too many open files" exception in server.log, I use "lsof | wc", then the result is larger than 1000000, so it is not a configuration issue. The result of "lsof | wc" is from 300000 to 1000000. And the value of "lsof -p {wildfly pid}" is 1534.
  If I use "lsof" list all open files, the result is as:

java      23032 23570     star  803r     FIFO                0,8       0t0 159435626 pipe
java      23032 23570     star  804r     FIFO                0,8       0t0 159427236 pipe
java      23032 23570     star  805r     FIFO                0,8       0t0 159416919 pipe
java      23032 23570     star  806r     FIFO                0,8       0t0 159425566 pipe

"23032" is the wildfly pid. This pid has more than 200 tid (thread id), each tid(thread?) open 1534 files. When sometime passed, the total number of opened files is larger than 1000000 and "Too many open files" is thrown.

Could anyone can help answer what is the root cause and how to fix the issue or give a workaround for this?

Many thanks for this help.

Comment: Open files depend extremely on the application and configuration. If 10.1. will not help you should add a bit more information. Also you might start a plain fresh server and add applications and configuration step by step to see when you run into this issue. This might give you a better hint whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

Try Wildfly 10.1. If you are using SSL there have been some bug fixes that may be relevant.